# Обновление данных в TableView

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть метод для заполнения таблицы TableView данными из БД, подскажите пожалуйста что мне нужно сделать что бы эти данные автоматически обновлялись

Вот метод для заполнения таблицы

```
public void buildData(){
    Connection table;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    table = DatabaseHandler.getDbConnection();
    data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    String PostSQL = "SELECT * from " + Constant.TABLE_OF_ORGANIZATION;
    try{
        rs =  table.createStatement().executeQuery(PostSQL);

        for(int i=0 ; i<rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
            final int j = i;
            TableColumn col = new TableColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1));
            col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList,String>, ObservableValue<String>>(){
                public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());
                }
            });

            tableView.getColumns().addAll(col);
            System.out.println("Column ["+i+"] ");
        }

        while(rs.next()){
            //Iterate Row
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for(int i=1 ; i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
                //Iterate Column
                row.add(rs.getString(i));
            }
            System.out.println("Row [1] added "+row );
            data.add(row);

        }
        tableView.setItems(data);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error on Building Data");
    }
}
```

Заранее благодарен.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой вариант - каждые n времени удалять все поля и заново их добавлять.

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        tableView.getItems().clear();

        while(rs.next()){
            //Iterate Row
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for(int i=1 ; i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
                //Iterate Column
                row.add(rs.getString(i));
            }

            System.out.println("Row [1] added "+row );
            data.add(row);
        }

        tableView.setItems(data);

    }, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
}
```

Сложнее - каждые n времени делать запрос в БД, получать ответ, сверять ответ с полями и если нужно - обновлять их.

Еще сложнее - реализовать шаблон producer/consumer, где producer будет создавать события обновления организации в БД, а consumer будет это событие ловить и изменять поле.

Comment: Большое спасибо, но столкнулся с проблемой в плане оптимизации, добавил поток но все равно грузит систему, есть советы что можно предпринять?

Comment: Как вариант увеличить интервалы, обновлять частями и прочие хитрости